# Cannot translate a content type "The configuration objects have different language codes so they cannot be translated"

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I cannot translate a content type

The configuration objects have different language codes so they cannot be translated:
node.type.article : fr
core.base_field_override.node.article.title : en

I think it was because by mistake the article was created in French then after I go back to en... But I don't know how to change it ?

I tried to fix this via drush :

```
drush cset node.type.article langcode en
```

but it doesn't seems to work so I would like to know how to fix it via the admin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export the configuration:

```
drush cex
```

then change the langcode in `sites/default/files/config_HASH/sync` and import the configuration again:

```
drush cim
```

Look for all non english langcodes that are in the base `sync` folder (or non default langcode, if you have another default language).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, was to make the content type translatable again together with the specific field with the wrong translation. Then add the correct translation.